# Limit of a sequence related to the exponential function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we already know that

$\{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\} \rightarrow e$.

How do we prove that:

$\{a_n\} \rightarrow a \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \{(1+\frac{a_n}{n})^n\} \rightarrow e^a$ ?

This was a lemma from my textbook for mathematical statistics. I found it obvious, but I couldn't formulate a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$(1 + \dfrac{a_n}{n})^n = \left((1 + \dfrac{a_n}{n})^\dfrac{n}{a_n}\right)^{a_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it seems like I'll have to use the limit of the "continuous" function of (1+1/n)^n instead of merely using the limit of the sequence (n taking on integer values). Are there any ways around it?

Comment: @RGG You can replace $\frac{n}{a_n}$ by its integer part and show that the difference doesn't change the limit, since $\frac{1}{\frac{n}{a_n}} - \frac{1}{[\frac{n}{a_n}]} \to 0$ and $\frac{n}{a_n} / [\frac{n}{a_n}] \to 1$

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to prove that
$$\log\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n \to a, $$
but since $a_n=a+o(1)$ as $n\to +\infty$ and $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$ as $x\to 0$, we have:
$$\log\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n = n\log\left(1+\frac{a}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=a+o(1)$$
as wanted.